# Rango de números estáticos como parámetro para una condición not in Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una consulta que me trae datos numéricos entre el 0 y 6:

```
SELECT n_dia FROM estructura_horario WHERE n_status = 1 AND n_id_estructura_jornada=1;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quiero una consulta que me retorne los numeros que faltan en ese rango, que seria del 4 al 6

He intentado pasar los numeros directo ya que no se alojan en ninguna tabla, pero no se como hacer esto, se me ocurrio algo como esto:

```
SELECT 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 NOT IN (SELECT n_dia FROM estructura_horario WHERE n_status = 1 AND n_id_estructura_jornada=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esto necesitas generar de algún modo la secuencia completa. Idealmente, si corresponde, deberías tener una tabla física con todos los números en el rango que manejas, de modo tal de incorporarla a tu propia consulta.

```
SELECT n_dia
       FROM mi_tabla_de_secuencia_completa 
       WHERE n_dia NOT IN (SELECT n_dia 
                                  FROM estructura_horario 
                                  WHERE n_status = 1 AND n_id_estructura_jornada=1);
```

Si no tuvieras esta tabla y quisieras generarla bajo demanda, un código habitual para generar una secuencia de números sería:

```
SELECT n_dia
       FROM (
          SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS n_dia FROM 
                (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
                (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
                (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
                (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
                (SELECT @row:=0) numbers
         ) NR
         where n_dia <= 31;
```

Técnicamente la consulta puede generar hasta 10.000 números (repitiendo los `joins` puedes agregar más), aunque en el `WHERE` del ejemplo lo limito a 31 dìas. Si usas esta opción simplemente remplaza `mi_tabla_de_secuencia_completa` por este código como subconsulta.